# Select/Deselect radio buttons in modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout-2.0

I have a modal and on my modal I have certain control and also 3 radio buttons. I want the user to be able to select/deselect a radio button OR I want a user to ONLY select 1 radio button. I am using knockoutjs to bind data to my modal.

Modal:

```
<div id="ModalGroup" class="modal hide fade" data-bind="with: Data" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Add Group</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">
                Group Name
            </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="GroupName" data-bind="value: GroupName" />
            </div>

            <label class="control-label">
                Group Description
            </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="GroupDescription" data-bind="value: GroupDescription" />
            </div>

            <label class="control-label">Group Scope</label>
            <div class="controls" id="scope">
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="Local" name="Local" value="Local" />
                    Local
                </label>
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="Global" name="Global" value="Global" />
                    Global
                </label>
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="Universal" name="Universal" value="Universal" />
                    Universal
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Security
                </label>
                <input id="IsSecurity" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-bind="value: IsSecurity" />
                Is Security?
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="CreateGroup" data-bind="click: vm.Save">Create Group</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
vm = {
        Data: ko.observable(),

        Add: function () {
            $("#ModalGroup").modal("show");

            vm.Data(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS({
                GroupName: "",
                GroupScope: "",
                GroupDescription: ""
            })));

            if (!vm.Bound) {
                ko.applyBindings(vm);
                vm.Bound = true;
            }
        }
}
```

I have tried to use `$('#ModalGroup').show('modal').on()` function and then I am able to select/deselect my radio buttons but then my bindings does not work accordingly. Not sure how put all of it together.

Jquery for select/delesect:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
   if (this.checked) {
       $(this).closest('.scope')
         .find('input[type=radio]').not(this)
         .prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```

The Jquery is what I used inside `$('#ModalGroup').show('modal').on()`

Comment: I found this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kappa/fD8V9/
and that is what I want on my Modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function (event) {
        // If the button is selected.
        if ($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
            // Remove the placeholder.
            $(this).removeClass("checked");
            // And remove the selection.
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            // If the button is not selected.
        } else {
            // Remove the placeholder from the other buttons.
            $("input[type='radio']").each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass("checked");
            });
            // And add the placeholder to the button.
            $(this).addClass("checked");
        }
    });
```

this will select/deselect radio buttons